# How to use a method from a different package?

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, import

I need to access classes from a separate package from the class I am working on however I cannot get it to work. I am currently working on ConcreteAccount in the PMSModel package and need to access methods from the classes in Account.Strategies.

I keep getting the "Cannot find symbol" error when trying to do this. I have another project that uses the exact same method that I am trying to use and there is no error. I have tried to access them when the classes have constructors and when they do not but I get the exact same error. I have an image of the error below:

[image: error being thrown]

Below is the code where I am trying to access the classes from the Account.Strategies package. The error itself is showing on the "Strategies" part of the statement.

```
package PMSModel;

import Account.Strategies.IAccountStrategy;

public class ConcreteAccount extends Account {

@Override
public IAccountStrategy selectStrategy(String accountType){
    IAccountStrategy strategy;

    switch(accountType){
        case "Patient":
            strategy = new Account.Strategies.PatientStrategy();
            break;
        case "Secretary":
            strategy = new Account.Strategies.SecretaryStrategy();
            break;
    }
    return strategy;
}
}
```

Below is a screenshot of how my packages and classes relate to each other:

[image: project file area]

I expect "strategy" to store the class so that I can access the methods of that particular class in Account.

Comment: Naming classes the same way as packages is really not a good idea. There's a reason naming conventions exist: packages should be all-lowercase, and classes should be CamelCase. Packages should contain start with the dns name of your company in reverse order: `com.yourcompany.yourproject.account.strategies`. Also, when asking about an error. Don't, ever, paraphrase the error. Post the exact and complete error message.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the error message in full. I'm new to Java and Netbeans and am using conventions taught by my University Lecturer. Hurts to see that he is teaching me the wrong practices :/

Comment: The error message shows you the problem: The compiler looks for an inner class Strategies in the class Account. Respect the standard Java naming conventions, and everything ill be much easier (and cleaner).

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at the actual naming conventions and bring it up with my Lecturer if he disagrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all, good practices for naming a package must be written in lowercase. 
Second the issue that you are facing is because you don't have a root package which should be shared by your project for example :

```
com.example.projectname
```

This should be your root and on this starts others packages

```
com.example.projectname.account.strategies
com.example.projectname.controller
com.example.projectname.guiview
com.example.projectname.pmsmodel
com.example.projectname.resources
```

FYI I'm agree  about what **JB Nizet** typed you.

**REFERENCES**

Java Code Conventions -> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I'm changing the names of my packages now. I'm not doing this for a company so should I ignore the 'com.example' part and just use the 'projectname.packagename' part?

Comment: For university projects yep but you can read Code Conventions in order to do good practices. the com.example is company name  which you have created it.. So perhaps you can use edu.myuniversity.projectname... So that identifies copyright and in what company has developed it.